# ошибка импорта react

Tags: reactjs, импорт, graphql

Не получается импортировать Categories.

текст ошибки:

Cannot find module '../../core/services/query/Categories.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/integrations/webpack/

Answer (score 1):

Надо так:

```
async componentDidMint() {
```

Comment: Так оно не может файл ресолвить графкл, а это уже вторая проблема :)

Comment: Хм.. Не обратил внимания... Тогда не знаю, может там лоадер не настроен?